# Error in php-ews package for SOAP client returned status of 401

Tags: laravel, exchange-server, php-ews

currently i am using  http://jamesarmes.com/php-ews/ php-ews package in laravel for exchange mail, my client activate TLS 1.2 security and emails stopes working and i am getting SOAP client returned status of 401 from exchange, please help me to resolve this issue for TLS 1.2

Here are some code snippet.

$this->client = new Client($host, $username, $password, $version);
$this->client->setCurlOptions(array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false));

i added too many options in curl like CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6 but not getting any solution, please help